# How can I get time differences between two events in the same table in Postgres SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have a table with two columns namely, type and time. Data consists of two types : A and B.

The actual data consists of both the types present alternatively in the table with their respective time stamps (i.e, row 1: a,t1; row2: b,t2; row3: a,t3; row4: b,t4). How can I calculate all the time differences between type A and type B (i.e, i need (t2-t1) and (t4-t3)).

Thanks, and i would appreciate answers using sql join

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What means alternatively - how is your data ordered? By timestamp?

Comment: If you want to calculate all the time differences between type A and type B, so why you need to calculate t4-t2 in your example? both t4 and t2 are in B type.

Comment: yes, ordered by timestamp....imagine those events are like the opening and closing of a door

Comment: @haytem - sorry for the typo, i meant t4-t3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT B.MyTIME-A.MyTIME 
FROM (SELECT MyROW , MyTYPE, MyTIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyTIME ASC) AS RNA FROM MyTable WHERE MyTYPE='A') A
INNER JOIN
(SELECT MyROW , MyTYPE, MyTIME, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyTIME ASC) AS RNB FROM MyTable WHERE MyTYPE='B')B
ON B.RNB=A.RNA
```